# OPENGL (GLFW), glDrawElements gives out "Acces.ViolationException"

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

(I'm a pretty new Coder (at least in Graphics programming), so don't be too harsh with me :( )

Today I tried to render a simple triangle using the C# implementation of OpenGL (GLFW), I followed the web tutorial from "LearnOpenGL.com" specifically the hello triangle tutorial.

I've completed the entire tutorial and expect the program to run and show me a beautifull triangle, instead it gives out the Error message:

> ```
> _glDrawElements(mode, count, type, indices)
> System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
> This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'"
> ```

I searched for a solution, but sadly couldn't find any, I completely checked my code with the tutorial
(which is where the error probably is, since I need to "transpose" it from C++ to C#) and couldn't find any errors.

Here's My Code:

```
class Implementation : App.Game
{

    uint VBO;
    uint VAO;
    uint EBO;
    uint VertexShader;
    uint FragmentShader;
    uint ShaderProgram;

    float[] vertices =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f
    };

    uint[] indices =
    {
            0, 1, 2,
            1, 2, 3
    };

    public Implementation(int windowWidth, int windowHeight, string windowTitle) : base(windowWidth, windowHeight, windowTitle)
    {
        // StartUp Code hier
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // Startet Komponenten und das Spiel
    }

    protected unsafe override void LoadResources()
    {
        // Lädt die hier angegebene Ressourcen

        // ShaderProgram initiieren
        // -
        // Vertex Shader
        VertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(VertexShader, Shader.vertexShader);
        glCompileShader(VertexShader);
        // Shader-Kompilationsfehler Check
        int[] succes = glGetShaderiv(VertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, 1);
        if (succes[0] == 0)
        {

            string Error = glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShader);
            Debug.WriteLine("VERTEX SHADER COMPILATION ERROR | " + Error);

        }
        // -
        // Fragment Shader
        FragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(FragmentShader, Shader.fragmentShader);
        glCompileShader(FragmentShader);
        // Shader-Kompilationsfehler Check
        succes = glGetShaderiv(FragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, 1);
        if (succes[0] == 0)
        {

            string Error = glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShader);
            Debug.WriteLine("FRAGMENT SHADER COMPILATION ERROR | " + Error);

        }
        // -
        // Shader zusammenlinken
        ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShader);
        glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
        // Linker-Fehler Check
        succes = glGetProgramiv(ShaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, 1);
        if (succes[0] == 0)
        {

            string Error = glGetProgramInfoLog(ShaderProgram);
            Debug.WriteLine("SHADER PROGRAM LINKING ERROR | " + Error);

        }
        // Unbenutzte Variablen entfernen
        glDeleteShader(VertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(FragmentShader);

        // Vertex- u. Bufferdaten laden und die Vertex Attribute konfigurieren
        

        glGenVertexArrays(1, (uint*)VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, (uint*)VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, (uint*)EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        fixed (float* v = &vertices[0])
        { 
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * vertices.Length, v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        fixed (uint* i = &indices[0])
        {
            glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uint) * indices.Length, i, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);

    }

    protected unsafe override void Render()
    {
        // Render Code hier
        // -
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // -
        // Erstes Dreieck
        glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

        Glfw.SwapBuffers(WindowManager.Window);
        Glfw.PollEvents();

    }

    protected override void Update()
    {
        // Führt auf allen Komponenten und auf dem Spiel die Update funktion durch
    }
}
```

And here´s the Shader Code:

```
public static string vertexShader = @"#version 330 core
                                layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
                                void main() 
                                {
                                    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition.x, aPosition.y, aPosition.z, 1.0);
                                }";

    public static string fragmentShader = @"#version 330 core
                                out vec4 FragColor;
                                void main() 
                                {
                                    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
                                }";
```

Just for clarification, the background code (LoadResources, Update, Render, Init) all works, I've checked multiple times.

Comment: Do you use [OpenTK](https://opentk.net/) or [SharpGL](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpgl)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue are the lines

> ```cs
> fixed (float* v = &vertices[0])
> ```
>
> ```cs
> fixed (uint* i = &indices[0])
> ```

`v` and `i` are just a pointer to the 1st elements of the managed arrays.

You have to created [Fixed Size Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers) to transfer the data arrays to the GPU. For instance use [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=netcore-3.1) to marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

```cs
int vertexSize = sizeof(float) * vertices.Length;
IntPtr vertexPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(vertexSize);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(vertices, vertexPtr, false);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize, vertexPtr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(vertexPtr);

int indexSize = sizeof(float) * vertices.Length;
IntPtr indexPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(indexSize);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(indices, indexPtr, false);

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexSize, indexPtr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(indexPtr);
```